# Oracle Plugin not working in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, installation, oracle-dbms

I am using GeoServer 2.2.5 & added 'geoserver-2.2.5-oracle-plugin.zip' at '..\geoserver 2.2.5\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib' to connect with Oracle data.

**after restarting GeoServer, No datastore like 'Oracle/Oracle NG' is found.**

The two jar files(in 'lib' directory) are -

1. ojdbc.jar ;
2. gt_jdbc_oracle_8.7.jar.

In the same process I installed 'MySql'Plugin & it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with MySQL, where I had accidentally installed the plugin jar's into the upper level lib directory.
Even when I added them to the correct directory, but not yet removed them from the upper lib, I had problems.
I suspect if you added -verbose onto the java start up command you'll find that another ojdbc.jar is being loaded first before the one in the WEB-INF\lib.
You will have to adjust your environment path variable to have the plugin jar to be first, or the only jar available.